# What does 辛苦了 mean?

Tags: meaning

The president of China, 习近平， is in 香港。 At the military parade， 阅兵时， he said, as he passed the troops, "同志们好“， then '辛苦了‘。

’辛苦了‘ 的意思是什么？ Perhaps： Thank you for your hard work。

Comment: yeah you're mostly correct, it's like "it's been hard times for you guys" and in this case, from the hard workings.

Comment: 辛苦了 standard phrase recognizing others' hard work, see jukuu for 100 samples

Answer (score 2):

"辛苦" as an adjective means "exhausting"

But '了' is a particle that follows a verb to indicate completion of the action

And "辛苦" as a verb means "work hard"

Therefore, "你們辛苦了" as a greeting  should mean: "you had worked hard/ you have been working hard"

Comment: ‘should mean'?? You are not sure?

Comment: May be native English speakers would phrase it differently.

Answer (score 2):

As a native Chinese speaker, I've been watching TV for several years.

When soldiers say "首长好。" (Greetings, our leader!) and Xi responds "同志们辛苦了。", I think it's better to be translated as

> Good job you've done. / You've been doing well.

That sounds strange but reasonable to me. First "辛苦" should not be translated into "exhaust", which means more "wear out" than "hard work". When Xi says "辛苦了", he means "(你们为人民服务)辛苦了", so the whole sentence should be "You've been **working hard** and it's good for you".

Comment: There was a big， very long pause  pause between 同志们好 and 辛苦了。 我在中央电视台看到。 This was not spoken as a sentence.

Comment: 那是仪式性要求，停顿对分析这个句子没有影响。It's harmonic requirements (not to speak too fast) and has no influence on our studying the sentence.